# Google charts getState() from separate function

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to get the current state of a dashboard control from a function outside the function that initiates the control. I assume its something along the lines of

```
var state = google.visualization.ControlWrapper('mc_picker').getState()
```

but maybe I'm way off. Can't seen to find any reference to this in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access charts and controls like that (though it would be cool to be able to).  The objects created by the Visualization API are only available via the variables used to store them, so if you want to access your control from outside your chart drawing function, the variable must be in scope for both functions:

```
function initialize {
    var control;
    function drawChart () {
        // create control object
    }
    function foo () {
        // get control object's state
    }
}
```